# Spring Data REST not including entity links in resource

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data, spring-data-rest

## Resolved By Oliver Gierke's Solution

Looks like this was a known bug in Spring 4.2.0, upgrading to 4.2.1 has provided the expected functionality

---

## Original Question

I'm working on moving my dev team over to Spring + WebMVC + Data-REST + Data-JPA + Spring HATEOAS for web applications. My current app is just going to maintain a list of our ongoing applications.

I'm running into an issue with my default Spring Data REST setup. **My resources aren't including their linked resource in their specific views, while they are included in the collection view.**

I'm not sure if this is intended behavior or not, so I'll include relevant configs and such at the end of this post.

`jv.local` is my dev box,
apps-list/app is where spring-data-rest is bound to (config included below)

Example:

```
curl jv.local:8080/apps-list/app/departments
```

Returns:

```
{
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://jv.local:8080/apps-list/app/departments{?page,size,sort}",
      "templated" : true
    }
  },
  "_embedded" : {
    "departments" : [ {
      "name" : "Dining",
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://jv.local:8080/apps-list/app/departments/1",
          "templated" : false
        },
        "institution" : {
          "href" : "http://jv.local:8080/apps-list/app/departments/1/institution",
          "templated" : false
        }
      }
    }, {
      "name" : "Housing",
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://jv.local:8080/apps-list/app/departments/2",
          "templated" : false
        },
        "institution" : {
          "href" : "http://jv.local:8080/apps-list/app/departments/2/institution",
          "templated" : false
        }
      }
    } ]
  }
}
```

(Note in particular that departments have their institution linked properly in _links)

However, pulling a specific department results in

```
curl jv.local:8080/apps-list/app/departments/1
{
  "name" : "Dining",
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://jv.local:8080/apps-list/app/departments/1",
      "templated" : false
    }
  }
}
```

Here the department has no associated institution listed. Is there a way to enable the institution in _links?

### Entity Definitions

**Department.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="department")
public class Department {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    
    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;
    
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name="institution", referencedColumnName="id")
    @RestResource
    private Institution institution;
    
    public Long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }
    
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    
    . . . more getters/setters like above
}
```

**Institution.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "institution")
public class Institution {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name", unique = true)
    private String name;

    public Long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    . . . name getter/setter
}
```

### Repositories

**DepartmentRepository.java**

```
@RestResource(rel="departments",path="departments")
public interface DepartmentRepository extends JpaRepository<Department, Long> {
}
```

**InstitutionRepository.java**

```
@RestResource(rel="institutions",path="institutions")
public interface InstitutionRepository extends JpaRepository<Institution, Long> {
    Institution findFirstByName(String name);
}
```

### Configs

Configs are included from a root AppConfig class via @Imports. AppConfig is specified via `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer` subclass as a member of `getRootConfigClasses()`.

AppConfig class is annotated with the following

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({my.packages, my.other.packages})
@EnableSpringDataWebSupport
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(my.repository.location)
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@Import({PersistenceConfiguration.class, RestConfiguration.class, MvcConfiguration.class, SecurityConfiguration.class})
```

**RestConfiguration.java**

```
@Configuration
public class RestConfiguration extends RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration {
    @Override
    public RepositoryRestConfiguration config() {
      RepositoryRestConfiguration config = super.config();
      config.setBasePath("/app");
      return config;
    }
}
```

### Version Information

- spring-webmvc, 4.2.0
- spring-context, 4.2.0
- spring-orm, 4.2.0
- spring-data-jpa 1.8.2
- jackson-core 2.6.1
- jackson-databind 2.6.1
- servlet 3.1.0
- spring-data-rest-webmvc 2.3.2
- spring-hateoas 0.18.0

**Please!** let me know if I can provide any more useful information, or possibly a working GH project. If this is intended behavior, is there any way to override, and force links to display?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a well-known – and thankfully already fixed – [bug in Spring 4.2](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13318). Upgrading to Spring 4.2.1 should fix that (or Spring Boot 1.3 M5).